# 404 not found after press button of form

Tags: php, html

I've been working with PhpStorm for some days and I've got a problem. When I try to press the button of my form, Firefox gives me the 404 page, opera says, that the button isn't pressed. However, if I put this code in the texteditor and run it, it works without any problems. Can somebody explain me where is my mistake?

P.S. I tried to find some pieces of advise in a search engine. Most advise to change some values in php.ini. I did it, but it doesn't work anyway.

```
 <form action = 'obr.php' method = 'post'>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'accept' value = 'Apply'>
</form>
```

obr.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
    echo "Accept exists";
}
else {
    echo "Accept doesn't exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe your PhpStorm is not well configured to use built-in web servers. Check for a message like "Please configure PHP interpreter to use built-in web server" at the bottom of PhpStorm. If the message is there, then configure it.

Comment: I use the local server and use the Interpreter of XAMPP(it's all on Linux). There are no messages about configuration with web server. Another php code works. I also use MySQL databse from XAMPP. Everything works except this POST query.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is not the same directory of php file the you have to put the right action url in `<form>` , check the url in your browser for the actual form and obr.php

Comment: form and php file are at the same directory. The form sees php file, but the result is false

Comment: In your php file cand you add just after <?php print_r($_POST); die; and see what's the result if it's a 404 then change the content of you php file and just set echo "true"; and open this file in your broser to see if the script is generated. Hope that will help you.